# Invalid date error in custom query in Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to prepare a chart using custom query (BigQuery) in Data Studio.However I get invalid  date error when using Data Studio Date Parameter `@DS_START_DATE` and `@DS_END_DATE`. Here is my query

```sql
SELECT cat_tbl.*,tag.Category_name 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
     (SELECT category FROM UNNEST(ana_cat) ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1) AS category,
     * 
   FROM `projectId.dataset.table1`) AS cat_tbl  
   RIGHT JOIN `projectId.dataset.table2` AS tag 
     ON cat_tbl.category=tag.Category_id
WHERE DATE(cat_tbl.date) BETWEEN @DS_START_DATE AND @DS_END_DATE
```

`cat_tbl.date` is `DATETIME` field.
When I run this I get following error

```
Invalid date: '20191014'

Error ID: 853185df
```

I am new to BigQuery and Data Studio.Any advice would be really helpfull.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at the example from [the Data Studio blog post](https://www.blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/introducing-bigquery-parameters-data-studio/), those query parameters aren't really dates (somewhat confusingly) but are strings in the format `YYYYMMDD`. So you need to parse them as dates in your query:

```sql
SELECT cat_tbl.*,tag.Category_name 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
     (SELECT category FROM UNNEST(ana_cat) ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1) AS category,
     * 
   FROM `projectId.dataset.table1`) AS cat_tbl  
   RIGHT JOIN `projectId.dataset.table2` AS tag 
     ON cat_tbl.category=tag.Category_id
WHERE DATE(cat_tbl.date)
    BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) AND
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
```

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't work..tried it again and worked.Anyway thanks